View all schemas/document sources in Vespa DB
I want to delete all the documents coming form a specific source in Vespa DB on my Linux machine but I don't know what the schema/source is called in the DB. I can not find in the cli documentation here an example of a query of how to list all schemas/source types?
Any idea how I can list all the schema types so I can identify which one I want to delete and then delete all documents from that source?

I assume you are running Vespa self-hosted and not https://cloud.vespa.ai/
I think the best option is to use the Deploy API documented at https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/deploy-rest-api-v2.html to extract the schema files
